# Odoo Unknown field in domain

Tags: python, xml, module, crm, odoo

I am trying to make some changes in the crm.lead model or more precisely inside the form view of opportunity. In the original, i have 2 buttons like "Mark as Win" and "Mark as Lost". I replaced these buttons with other 4 buttons like "FFS - Win", "FFS - Lost", "Package - Win", and "Package - Lost". Now i want to replace label "Won" and "Lost", which is displayed on the green or red background with 4 other label, equal to buttons.

At this moment i did:

Inherited view(XML)

```
<record id="cmp_crm_lead_form" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">cmp.crm.lead.form</field>
        <field name="model">crm.lead</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="crm.crm_case_form_view_oppor"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <data>
                <button name="action_set_won" position="replace">
                    <button name="ffs_set_won" string="FFS - Success" type="object" class="oe_highlight o_wow" attrs="{'invisible': ['|', ('active','=',False), ('probability', '=', 100)]}"/>
                    <button name="package_set_won" string="Package - success" type="object" class="oe_highlight o_wow" attrs="{'invisible': ['|', ('active','=',False), ('probability', '=', 100)]}"/>
                </button>
                <xpath expr="//form/header/button[2]" position="replace">
                    <button name="ffs_set_lost" string="FFS - Lost" type="action" class="oe_highlight" context="{'default_lead_id': active_id}" attrs="{'invisible': [('active', '=', False),('probability', '&lt;', 100)]}"/>
                    <button name="package_set_lost" string="Package - Lost" type="action" class="oe_highlight" context="{'default_lead_id': active_id}" attrs="{'invisible': [('active', '=', False),('probability', '&lt;', 100)]}"/>
                </xpath>
                <xpath expr="//form/sheet/div[2]" position="replace">
                    <div class="label label-danger pull-right" attrs="{'invisible': [('ffs_lost', '=', False)]}">FFS - Lost</div>
                    <div class="label label-danger pull-right" attrs="{'invisible': [('package_lost', '=', False)]}">Package - Lost</div>
                </xpath>
                <xpath expr="//form/sheet/div[3]" position="replace">
                    <div class="label label-success pull-right" attrs="{'invisible': [('ffs_success', '=', False)]}">FFS - Success</div>
                    <div class="label label-success pull-right" attrs="{'invisible': [('package_success', '=', False)]}">Package - Success</div>
                </xpath>
            </data>
        </field>
    </record>
```

Model(Python)

```
class CrmLead(models.Model):
_inherit = 'crm.lead'

ffs_success = fields.Boolean(default=False, readonly=True)
ffs_lost = fields.Boolean(default=False, readonly=True)
package_success = fields.Boolean(default=False, readonly=True)
package_lost = fields.Boolean(default=False, readonly=True)
```

It worked until i added invisible attribute. Now i cant enter to the form view, because i am getting an error:

```
Uncaught Error: Unknown field ffs_lost in domain [["ffs_lost","=",false]]
```

The problem concerns to the every of these 4 fields in the model.
Module is updated, fields exists in the database, and i can see them in the developer mode, but odoo still cant recognize them.

Comment: You need to add your new fields (`ffs_success`, `ffs_lost`, `package_success`, `package_lost`) to the form view if you want to use them in the domains. You can hide them (by adding `invisible="1"`) if you do not want to actually display them.

Comment: @Naglis post it as your answer.